# How to convert String date to Date?

Tags: java, string, date, date-format

I have done following code:

```
String str = "2013-01-17 11:26";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(str);
System.out.println("str :"+str);
System.out.println("Date :"+date);
```

**Output**

```
str :21-01-2013 11:26 
Date :Sat Feb 21 11:01:00 IST 2015
```

But something is wrong. I expect out as same as string date. i.e. Thu Jan 21 11:26:00 IST 2013

Comment: Yes, "hh:MM" should be "hh:mm"

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong format. `MM` is for `month`, and `mm` is for `minutes`, and for `hours` use `HH`. See [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for various other formats.

Change your format to: -

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code should work well:

```
try{
String str = "2013-01-17 11:26";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
Date date = (Date)dateFormat.parse(str);
System.out.println("str :"+str);
System.out.println("Date :"+date);
}
catch(Exception e){
   e.getStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can also create Date instance without creating DateFormat instance as below: Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str);

Comment: Well, you are still creating a DateFormat instance in that case. You should rather say, you can avoid an extra reference to that instance.

Comment: @RiponAlWasim This answer is incorrect. Better to edit it or remove it. `m` is minutes not month. It should be `M` for month.

Answer (score -2):

Just Using of DateFormat Class:

```
ateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Better to edit it or remove it. `m` is minutes not month. It should be `M` for month.